# Git and KDevelop

Tags: c++, git, kdevelop

I'm starting programming with KDevelop and Git.

I'm creating a project in C++ with KDevelop 4.4.1 and actually I've a Git account in Assembla.

I'm able to create an "internal git repository", doing commits with KDevelop.

I was researching about how I can PUSH my project into my account, but I didn't found enough information. How I can push my project to my repo in Assembla?

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Answer (score 6):

Pushing generally is done like this:

Before the first push you should add a remote:

```
git remote add origin pathToRepositoryInAssembla
```

Now for the first push (I'm assuming your default branch is master)

```
git push -u origin master
```

This will push your changes and git will no assign the `origin/master` to your local master. After this by using

```
git push
```

It will automatically push all “assigned” branches that contain changes.

For more information on how to use git refer to the [official handbook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started). For more information on remotes refer to [Working with remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

Comment: Your answer help me to do a first push to my remote repo. However, I was no using the KDevelop IDE directly to do the task...